# How to stop a variable from resetting when a cell is selected in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, reset, uicollectionviewcell, selected

I am trying to create a matching game using a UICollectionView. I have a method for a `UICollectionView` with some properties:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var definitionSelectedText:String = "None"
    var boatTypeSelectedText:String = "None"
    if cellSelected == false {
        if indexPath.item < 7 {
            definitionSelectedText = definitions[indexPath.item]
            println(definitionSelectedText)
            println(boatTypeSelectedText)
        } else if indexPath.item > 6 {
            boatTypeSelectedText = boatTypes[indexPath.item - 7]
            println(definitionSelectedText)
            println(boatTypeSelectedText)
        }
        cellSelected = true
```

I also have this method:

```
switch indexPath.item {
        case 7:
            switch definitionSelectedText {
            case "Used to carry the pharoah":
                if boatTypeSelectedText == "Royal Boat" {
                    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                        cellTitle.hidden = true
                        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                    }
               }
```

The problem that's happening is that `definitionSelectedText` resets to `"None"` when `indexPath.item` `7` is selected or any other ones. How can I prevent `definitionSelectedText` from resetting to `"None"` when an `indexPath.item < 6` is selected? I appreciate any support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `definitionSelectedText` to 'None' at the start of the function.  The `defintionSelectedText` is only set to something else when the `indexPath` is less than 7, so naturally, when indexPath==7 it won't be changed.  7 is not less than 7.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, is there anything I could do to make it so it didn't reset when the `indexPath` was 7 or higher? Possibly pass the variable on to when the `indexPath` is 7 or higher?

Comment: Don't set it to "None" before the if?

Comment: I tried that; when I set it to just `var definitionSelectedText:String`, I get this error whenever I try to use that variable: `Variable 'definitionSelectedText' used before being intialized`.

Comment: Then you either need to set it "None" within the body of the else, or declare it as an optional and unwrap it as required.